# subprocess stderr vs sys.stderr

Tags: python, stderr

I'm not sure whether the question is a Python or shell question.

I've got a Python program that uses a subprocess call on a command which can emit an error message on stderr. My own program also uses sys.stderr to log errors. Here's a simple example, with a command (ls *.foobar) that fails:

```
import sys,subprocess

sys.stderr.write("--Hello\n")
try:
    subprocess.check_call("ls *.foobar",shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    sys.stderr.write("Command failed\n")
sys.stderr.write("--Bye\n")
```

When I run this code, the ouptut on the console (from stderr) is the following:

> --Hello
>   ls: cannot access '*.foobar': No such file or directory
>   Command failed
>   --Bye

If I redirect stderr to a file (e.g. using python myscript.py 2> log), the file contains the following:

> ls: cannot access '*.foobar': No such file or directory
>   --Hello
>   Command failed
>   --Bye

Is there a way to keep the order of the messages in the file (other than using an explicit redirection of stderr on a file in the subprocess call) ?

This problem resembles some standard stdout/stderr issues but, here, everything is supposed to be on stderr.

Comment: for the record: such behaviour does not happen always, it's not deterministic (for example on my system it doesn't now). See Martin's reply for the reason why it can happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *flush* data writter to the `stderr` descriptor:

```
sys.stderr.write("--Hello\n")
sys.stderr.flush()
```

stdio is line buffered when connected to a terminal, and using a fixed buffer when connected to a pipe. You are writing a `\n` newline character which triggers a flush when connected to the terminal but, but without that per-line flush you don't write enough to `stderr` to trigger a buffer flush before the final flush when Python exits.

If you use `print(..., file=sys.stderr)` you can tell `print()` to issue the `flush()` call by adding `flush=True`:

```
print("--Hello", file=sys.stderr, flush=True)
```

Another way for you to handle this is to 'capture and release' the stderr output of the child process:

```
sys.stderr.write("--Hello\n")
try:
    subprocess.check_call("ls *.foobar", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    sys.stderr.write(e.stderr)
    sys.stderr.write("Command failed\n")
sys.stderr.write("--Bye\n")
```

The `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` addition tells `subprocess` to capture the stderr output of the command, and you can find that output as the `e.stderr` attribute of the `CalledProcessError` exception.